# Width of knitr code chunk where there is a call to source() in a chunk

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have a R script file named `f2.R` with the following contents:

```
f2 <- function(Delta, delta, sigma){
  pnorm(Delta, mean=delta, sd=sigma) - pnorm(-Delta, mean=delta, sd=sigma) 
}
```

Now, I have the following `Rmd` file:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse=TRUE, tidy=TRUE, R.options=list(width=20))
```

```{r define_f1}
f1 <- function(Delta, delta, sigma){
  pnorm(Delta, mean=delta, sd=sigma) - pnorm(-Delta, mean=delta, sd=sigma) 
}
```

```{r show_f1}
f1
```

```{r source_f2}
source("f2.R")
```

```{r show_f2}
f2
```
````

And this is the html output:

[image]

As you can see, the width option defined by `R.options=list(width=20)` has no effect on the last chunk. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `read_chunk`.

The R script `f2.R`:

```
# ---- source_f2 ----
f2 <- function(Delta, delta, sigma){
  pnorm(Delta, mean=delta, sd=sigma) - pnorm(-Delta, mean=delta, sd=sigma) 
}
```

The `Rmd` file:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse=TRUE, tidy=TRUE, tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=20))
```

```{r define_f1}
f1 <- function(Delta, delta, sigma){
  pnorm(Delta, mean=delta, sd=sigma) - pnorm(-Delta, mean=delta, sd=sigma) 
}
```

```{r show_f1}
f1
```

```{r read_f2, include=FALSE}
knitr::read_chunk("f2.R")
```

```{r source_f2, include=FALSE}
```

```{r show_f2}
f2
```
````

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually `options(width = 20)` would work, but not when printing a function.  You'll need something like

`cat(deparse(f2, width = 20), sep = "\n")`

Comment: You say *but not when printing a function*. However my chunk named `show_f1` prints a function, and the width option works for this chunk.

Comment: Put `options(width=50)` just before the line where you print f1, and you'll still see a 20 char wide f1.  `knitr` is doing something special with the `R.options=list(width=20)` setting, it's not the same as `options(width=20)`.

Comment: Anyway I don't want to use something like `cat(deparse(f2, width = 20), sep = "\n")`, even if it would give the desired output. This is not comfortable for the reader of my html document (by the way this reader is not assumed to be a fluent R user able to understand a code like `cat(deparse...)`). I really want that the reader sees the code of the `f2` function appearing when I type `f2`.

Comment: A couple of alternatives:  1. edit f2.R so f2 has 20 character lines.  It will display the way you entered it. 2. Hide the deparse call by putting it in an echo=FALSE code chunk.